# jqueryui frame dialog and multiple buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here is what I have..I am using the jquery.FrameDialog plugin. When the dialog box opens up, there are 2 buttons. One for let's say open google.com and second button to open stackoverflow.com

Problem is that the default url works fine, but using the button like this: `$dialog.load("http://www.google.com");` it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my full code:

```
   $('#mydialog').click(function(){
          var $dialog = jQuery.FrameDialog.create({
          url: 'http://www.yahoo.com',
          loadingClass: 'loading-image',
          title: 'IP Tracing',
          width: 1100,
          height: 700,
          autoOpen: false,
          overlay: {
          opacity: 0.5,
          background: "black"
          },
          buttons: {
                 "google": function() {
                        $dialog.load("http://www.google.com");
                 },
                 "stackoverflow": function() {
                        $dialog.load("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
                 },
                 "Exit": function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                 }
          }
     });

     $dialog.dialog('open');
     return false;
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe there is special and comfortable interface for changing urls for this plugin, but you can always lead your code to do what you want.

```
$('#box').click(function(){
          var $dialog = jQuery.FrameDialog.create({
          url: 'http://www.yahoo.com',
          loadingClass: 'loading-image',
          title: 'IP Tracing',
          width: 1100,
          height: 700,
          autoOpen: false,
          overlay: {
          opacity: 0.5,
          background: "black"
          },
          buttons: [
                 {
                     text: 'google',
                     click: function() {
                            $(this).find('iframe').attr('src', "http://www.google.com")
                     }
                 },
                 {
                     text: 'Exit',
                     click: function() {
                            $(this).dialog( "close" );
                     }
                 }
          ]
     });
```

You can simply find an iframe and say this directly to change the url

Comment: Thanks. That works for me as it accomplishes what my end result should be!