# Multiple actions on Form Submit

Tags: java, javascript, xml, jsp

I have a .jsp page with 3 frames. The first frame contains a form which takes in a user ID. This form links to another .jsp which creates a token for the user and displays his information in the 2nd frame. The 3rd frame is supposed to take the token from the 2nd jsp which is passed to the 3rd jsp which returns an XML file of the user's access. How would I get the Submit button to open both of these frames? or should I have two separate buttons?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841824/how-to-perform-multiple-actions-with-one-form/7842438#7842438

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this previous question it may be able to help. It focuses on using the onClick function within jQuery.

[jqueryui frame dialog and multiple buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989935/jqueryui-frame-dialog-and-multiple-buttons)